# Adding One Distinct Point of Color

Tags: r

I am trying to make the maximum of this vector very visible by putting in a distinct red circle at the max

```
myBoston[max(myBoston$crim),]
plot(density(myBoston$crim)) 
points(x = myBoston$crim[max(myBoston$crim)] , y = 0, col = "red")
rug(myBoston$crim)
```

However when I run the code, the point does not appear.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Can you try to explain what you are trying to get?

Comment: I made an edit does this help?

Comment: Not sure why you can't  see the red circle. What about when you do this? ggplot(myBoston, aes(crim)) + 
  geom_density() +
  geom_point(aes(x = myBoston$crim[max(myBoston$crim)],
                 y = 0), col = "red")

Comment: like @lizzie I get the red circle too.  You may not be seeing it because it is an empty circle. To make it more distinctive,  try `points(x = myBoston$crim[max(myBoston$crim)] , y = 0, col = "red", pch=16)`